# Add icon infront of electron js Notification title bar like app.setUserModelID Is used to display the application name in notification title bar

Tags: angular, electron

How to add icon infront of electron js Notification title bar like app.setUserModelID Is used to display the application name in notification title bar how to show icon in front of app.setUserModelId('Test Application') like I want to display a icon of my application infront of it.

I did not know how to do it i referred website but not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.